# Record Count (Nested??)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL `select` statement which works perfectly except I need to embed a count function (line 7 & 8).

```
select '1' = DYN_PORDERS.ID, '2' = DYN_PORDERS.SupplierID,'3' = 
DYN_PORDERS.Revision2,  
'4' = DYN_PORDERS.ItemID,  '5' = DYN_PORDERS.OrderNumber, '12' = '',
'6' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.SCompany, '7' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.SCode, '8' = 
SYS_SUPPLIERS.SCIPEMail, '9' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.SCIPContact, 
'10' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.SPDRemitType, '11' = SYS_SUPPLIERS.SCIPFax,
(SELECT count(DYN_PORDERS.OrderNumber) FROM DYN_PORDERS where OrderNumber = 
'5') AS column3
from DYN_PORDERS 
inner join  SYS_SUPPLIERS 
on SYS_SUPPLIERS.ID = DYN_PORDERS.SupplierID 
where DYN_PORDERS.OrderStatus1 = 1 and DYN_PORDERS.ItemID = 1
order by DYN_PORDERS.OrderNumber asc, DYN_PORDERS.itemid asc
```

The nested `select` count statement returns 0 but we have four records in the table.

I have tried to reference the Variable or Column Name '5' from the first select statement in the embedded one, but it returns 0.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Mike

Comment: Note`'5' `is not a column name. It is a string literal.

Comment: ok - I can see that, how would i reference back to the Column Name '5'?

Comment: This is a strange syntax. Which DBMS is this? `'5'` is a string. If you want alias names, then you should use double quotes `"5"`. And you should use standard SQL for this anyway: `DYN_PORDERS.OrderNumber AS "5"`.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Just changed the code to your suggestion and now i am getting an error on the embbed statement saying that "5" invalid Column Name.

Comment: DBMS = MS SQL Ver 14

Comment: You are getting closer ;-) You cannot use the alias name in the subquery. The alias name is only given at the end of execution; the subquery is evaluated before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `ordernumber` in the subquery, then use this name. Use table aliases to tell the outer table from the inner one.

```
select 
  p.id as "1", 
  p.supplierid as "2",
  p.revision2 as "3",  
  p.itemid as "4",  
  p.ordernumber as "5", 
  '' as "12",
  s.scompany as "6", 
  s.scode as "7",
  s.scipemail as "8", 
  s.scipcontact as "9", 
  s.spdremittype as "10", 
  s.scipfax as "11",
  (select count(*) from dyn_porders p2 where p2.ordernumber = p.ordernumber) as column3
from dyn_porders p
inner join sys_suppliers s on s.id = p.supplierid 
where p.orderstatus1 = 1 
  and p.itemid = 1
order by p.ordernumber asc, p.itemid asc;
```

Please note that single quotes are for string literals and double quotes for names.

Comment: I have changed my column names and the way in which i defined them along with the table names too.  All is good, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select p.ID as col_1, p.SupplierID as col_2, p.Revision2 as col_3,  
       p.ItemID as col_4, p.OrderNumber as col_5, '' as col_12,
       s.SCompany as col_6, s.SCode as col_7, s.SCIPEMail as col_8,
       s.SCIPContact as col_9, s.SPDRemitType as col_10, s.SCIPFax as col_11,
       (select count(*)
        from DYN_PORDERS p2
        WHERE p2.OrderNumber = 5
       ) as column3
from DYN_PORDERS  p inner join
     SYS_SUPPLIERS s 
     on s.ID = p.SupplierID 
where p.OrderStatus1 = 1 and p.ItemID = 1
order by p.OrderNumber asc, p.itemid asc;
```

Notes:

- I strongly recommend that you *not* name columns as numbers.  This is just confusing and requires escape characters (which might vary by database).
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations of the table names.  Queries are easier to write and to read.
- Don't use single quotes around numeric constants.